# field must be unique on OneToOne field in Django DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using `Django 2.x` and **DRF**.

I have a model to save rating for each entity

```
class UserRideRating(models.Model):
    user_ride = models.OneToOneField(UserRide, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_ride_rating')
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[validate_rating_range]
    )
```

and **serializers.py**

```
class UserRideRatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRideRating
        fields = ('id', 'user_ride', 'rating')
```

I have a view to create rating object if not already exists or update the rating if already exists. Also, I want to check validation using default Serializer validation and thus my view is like

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def rate(request):
    serializer = UserRideRatingSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        # create or update data
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When on passing data from the postman, it gives an error as

```
{
    "user_ride": [
        "This field must be unique."
    ]
}
```

How can I enable check for only valid data and not the uniqueness of the field? Although `user_ride` should be unique, it can pass in the request data.

Comment: Are you trying to turn off the validation for `user_ride` field?

Comment: No, I don't want to turn off validation completely for this field because it should be checked for `required` and also a valid UUID field.

Comment: Sorry.... I don't understand the exact requirement :(

Comment: **UserRide** model has UUID `id` field (primary key), so `user_ride` should be a valid UUID field and also is required in every request. Therefore, I just want to skip unique check leaving behind default validation checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to supply the serializer with the existing instance of `UserRideRating` if you want to skip this unique check.

Since you are not supplying the serializer with the instance it is considering you are creating a new one with the same `UserRide` id.

Use this code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def rate(request):
    user_ride_id = request.data.get('user_ride')
    try:
        instance = UserRideRating.objects.get(user_ride_id=user_ride_id)
    except UserRideRating.DoesNotExist:
        instance=None
    serializer = UserRideRatingSerializer(instance, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        # create or update data
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: How should I Add it in a CBV ?, I am using generic views